# Search and replace data-reactid

Tags: javascript

I am trying to look for data-reactid value and replace it with another value.

Here is the code:

Book a Room.

trying to use the code to replace ".0.2.2" with ".0.2.3"

```
(function () {
    var link = document.querySelectorAll('a[data-reactid*=".0.2.2"]') //change example.com to any domain you want to target
    var searchString = ".0.2.2" //the string to be searched forEach
    var replacementString = ".0.2.3" //the replacement for the searched string 
    
    links.forEach(function(link){
        var original = link.getAttribute("data-reactid");
        var replace = original.replace(searchString,replacementString)
        link.setAttribute("data-reactid",replace)
    })
})();
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? data-reactid is an attribute managed internally by react and isn't something you want to messing with.

Comment: You should replace `var link` with `var links`.

Answer (score 0):

Just change this

```js
var link = document.querySelectorAll('a[data-reactid*=".0.2.2"]')
```

to this

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[data-reactid*=".0.2.2"]')
```

#### But keep in mind that you should not change the attributes set by `React` itself